# Strange behavior using Data::Dump in combination with JSON::XS

Tags: json, perl

I am trying to use `JSON::XS` to export data from a Perl hash to a Python dictionary. I would like to have numbers exported as numbers (and not as unicode text). But it seems it is difficult to achieve in one case:

```
use Data::Dump qw(dump);
use JSON::XS;
my $h={a=> 1};
dump($h);
my $js = encode_json $h;
print "$js\n";
```

This exports the number 1 as a string: (the output is)

```
{ a => 1 }
{"a":"1"}
```

but only if I use `Data:Dump::dump`. If I remove the line `dump($h)` it gives

```
{"a":1}
```

as is the output I expect (and need).

I have tested this using Perl version 5.14 and 5.16 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl scalars can be multiple things, and get automatically transformed between kinds of things depending on how they're used. You can see what kind of thing you're dealing with by using [Devel::Peek](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CookBookB/DevelPeek.pod). Here's an example.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Peek ();

my $h = { foo => 42 };

Devel::Peek::Dump( $h );
```

**Output**

```
SV = IV(0x7fd5520291e8) at 0x7fd5520291f8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,ROK)
  RV = 0x7fd552003438
  SV = PVHV(0x7fd552008d20) at 0x7fd552003438
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (SHAREKEYS)
    ARRAY = 0x7fd551e003f0  (0:7, 1:1)
    hash quality = 100.0%
    KEYS = 1
    FILL = 1
    MAX = 7
    Elt "foo" HASH = 0xa8c24522
    SV = IV(0x7fd5520289f0) at 0x7fd552028a00
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (IOK,pIOK)
      IV = 42
```

That's a whole bunch of internal information about our anonymous hash, but the important bit is on the last line, which is in a group of stuff that describes the hash element `foo`. It says `IV = 42`, indicating that this scalar (the hash value associated to `foo`) is an **I** nteger **V** alue.

What happens if we run this through `Data::Dump` first?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Devel::Peek ();
use Data::Dump ();

my $h = { foo => 42 };

Data::Dump::dump( $h );
Devel::Peek::Dump( $h );
```

**Output**

```
SV = IV(0x7fce39829230) at 0x7fce39829240
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (PADMY,ROK)
  RV = 0x7fce39803438
  SV = PVHV(0x7fce39808d20) at 0x7fce39803438
    REFCNT = 1
    FLAGS = (OOK,SHAREKEYS)
    AUX_FLAGS = 0
    ARRAY = 0x7fce3940a340  (0:7, 1:1)
    hash quality = 100.0%
    KEYS = 1
    FILL = 1 (cached = 0)
    MAX = 7
    RITER = -1
    EITER = 0x0
    RAND = 0x3bebb965
    Elt "foo" HASH = 0x525af8b0
    SV = PVIV(0x7fce3982b238) at 0x7fce39828a00
      REFCNT = 1
      FLAGS = (IOK,POK,pIOK,pPOK)
      IV = 42
      PV = 0x7fce39430e20 "42"\0
      CUR = 2
      LEN = 16
```

Our hash has changed quite a bit by being run through `Data::Dump`. In particular, the hash value 42 now has a field called `PV` which is the string `"42"`. That's because when you have a scalar that contains a number, and you use it in a context expecting a string, Perl silently converts it to a string type. (Actually, this is an even specialer type that contains both a string *and* a number simultaneously. If you really want to freak people out you can even make them [different things](http://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar/Util.html#%24var-%3D-dualvar%28-%24num%2C-%24string-%29).)

So `Data::Dump` has caused your number to be stringified, and `JSON::XS`, which looks under the hood to see what kind of thing every scalar is, interprets it as a string.

So there are a couple options.

**Option the First**

Get your string of JSON before using `Data::Dump`. This is probably the easiest.

**Option the Second**

Add zero to every numeric value before you serialize to JSON, which will force them into a numeric context.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use JSON::XS;

my %h;
$h{a} = "42";
say encode_json( \%h );
$h{a} += 0;
say encode_json( \%h );
```

**Output**

```
{"a":"42"}
{"a":42}
```

More on how JSON::XS handles serialization heuristics can be found in the docs:

- [Mapping Perl to JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::XS#PERL---JSON)

Comment: Wow! Great explanation. But I have a large hash and it is not practically possible to manually add zero to each `int`. Also it is not easy to serialize before using `Data::Dump`. This is because I actually use `Data::Dump::pp` to get a string of the current hash which is dumped to a file, which may later be used as a config file.

Comment: @HåkonHægland, why can't you just do `my $js = encode_json $h;` before you call `Data::Dump`?

Comment: I could try, but then I have to rewrite some logic in my program. After I use `Data::Dump::pp` I add more items to the hash, before finally part of it is written to the `json` file.

Comment: Maybe you should try constructing two separate hashes from a common source. What you're doing sounds a little messy.

Comment: Maybe..:) But why does not `Devel::Peek::Dump` produce the same behavior as `Data::Dump`? I tried to run `Devel::Peek::Dump` twice and the flags of the scalar did not change at all..

Comment: I found the reason for the behavior. See my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the issue has been resolved in the CPAN bug list for `Data::Dump`

[Bug #86592 for Data-Dump: undesirable change of SV flags](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=86592#txn-1325365) .

The issue is a the following line in the [source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/GAAS/Data-Dump-1.22/lib/Data/Dump.pm):

```
    elsif (do {no warnings 'numeric'; $$rval + 0 eq $$rval}) {
```

which changes the flags of the integers such that JSON::XS believs it is a string.

(When will the module be revised with the bugfix ?? Somebody knows?)